Plotting individual points of a lognormal BRM
I apologize if I am titled this question oddly, I've never had a situation like this.
I am creating a BRMS model shown here:
model1 <- brm(distance ~ time + height + (1|sid), data = a03,
             family = lognormal(),
             prior = c(set_prior("normal(0,1)", class = "b")), 
             init = "random", 
             chains = 4, iter = 4000, warmup = 2000, thin = 1,
             cores = getOption("mc.cores", 4L),
             control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95, max_treedepth = 15),
             silent = TRUE, seed = 13, backend = "rstan", save_pars = save_pars(all = TRUE)

with family = lognormal(), which I then plot like this:
model1.gge   <- ggemmeans(model1, terms = c("height"))
model1.plot  <- plot(model1.gge,add.data=TRUE)+theme_bw()+theme(text = element_text(size = 15))

However add.data=TRUE is plotting the raw data instead of data transformed to lognormal:

You can see the difference in scale between the scatter plot and the plotted BRMS. I have been looking up plotting data with the BRM, but I don't know the correct phrasing for this in the BRM manual posted on R-projects. Can anyone give me some direction as to what parameter I need to look up to transform the plotted points? Thank you for your time!

Specifying family does not transform the data.  It simply defines the response distribution and the link function.

The default link function for lognormal() in brms is identity. So, you are actually getting the expected output. However you should not use ggemmeans() to generate the predictions here because it is giving you the prediction for different levels of height, either averaged over all levels of time or at the mean value of time if time is continuous. So that prediction will not necessarily look like a line going right through the middle of the points on the scatterplot. I would recommend reading the documentation of emmeans and ggeffects package.

Also, if you can provide a reproducible example, that would be helpful. It's hard to diagnose what is going on without having access to the data frame a03. For example I can't tell what the values of time are, or whether time and height are discrete or continuous variables.
